# Updating static variables across multiple server instances

Tags: java, server

1. I have a static variable which I update through an Admin console the information gets updated both in the static variable and the DB.
2. Problem is we have multiple server instances.
3. When I update the information through one server instance it updates the value properly but the problem is the static variables.
4. The static variables are updated in the server instance through which I added the data but not in other server instances.

I can update the static variable in some periodic time span but is there any other way in which we could handle this.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Why you cannot go over all your servers and update your variables?

Comment: You can't magically "inject" an update of a static variable in a remote JVM. You will have to create some interface on the server for intercepting update commands. When that's in place you simply loop over your server instances and submit the command to update the variable in question on each server.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can create background process in your application that polls DB for this value with specified interval. 
   it's simplest and fastest way but not efficient.
2. you can use publish/subscribe mechanism to push this value to all your servers. In big systems it can be zookeeper or some JMS brokers. If system is not so big you can look for some embedded publish/subscribe solution.

Comment: A simple solution is to create a simple java servlet, but it supposes that each instance knows the others, to call the servlet.

Comment: this solution is not reliable. You need to design your system to handle connection problems, race conditions, server fails

Comment: I already thought of the first method to handle this issue but since it is inefficient I decided not to go with it.

Comment: With regard to the second option I cant quite get what you are trying to say sorry. Can you please give a brief info on that

Comment: please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern. There are a lot of 3rd parties that provide reliable publish/subscribe messaging. But it has disadvantage - additional infrastructure that can be expensive for small or middle companies. So there some embedded  solutions that are simpler(just java library). You can look to distributed cache solutions(google it). I personally had experience with hazelcast. My suggestion is "spend 1 hour on implementing 1 option and forget about it while it's a problem or really needed". Keep it simple

Answer (score 0):

You can store the static variable in cache , not in every single server instance .
Every server instance retrieve the static variable from cache .

Update the static variable to DB directly and then reload cache .

Comment: How do the other instances know that they need to reload the cache?

Comment: Other server instances needn't to know reloading cache . All of server instances retrieve that value from cache .   Reload cache after updating DB .

Comment: Then the question is how do you reload the cache?